# Return first item in a map/list/sequence that satisfies a predicate

Tags: clojure

I am looking for a function that returns the first element in a sequence for which an fn evaluates to true. For example:

```
(first-map (fn [x] (= x 1)) '(3 4 1))
```

The above fake function should return 1 (the last element in the list). Is there something like this in Clojure?

Comment: why not just `(first (filter #(= % 1) '(3 4 1))`?

Comment: @4e6 Because that would apply the function to every element on the list, which might be undesirable on a large list.

Comment: Map is lazy, so I don't think it would. You ought to test that though.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
user=> (defn find-first
         [f coll]
         (first (filter f coll)))
#'user/find-first
user=> (find-first #(= % 1) [3 4 1])
1
```

*Edit:* A concurrency. :) No. It does not apply `f` to the whole list. Only to the elements up to the first matching one due to laziness of `filter`.

Comment: Thanks @kotarak, my concern is that this would process all of the elements in the collection, which is undesirable on a large list.  Perhaps I need to create a function that recurs until it finds the lement that satisfies the condition.

Comment: @Matthew modulo chunked sequences. There `f` may be applied to more elements depending on the chunk size.

Comment: using `filter` or `some` takes more resources. alternatively, `reduced` can shortcut the whole calculation while takes less resources: `(reduce #(when (= %2 50000000) (reduced %2)) nil (range))`.

Comment: @xando Did you use something like the following to prove it?`user=> (def input (range))
#'user/input
user=> (time (some #{50000000} input))
"Elapsed time: 3909.789411 msecs"
50000000
user=> (time (reduce #(when (= %2 50000000) (reduced %2)) nil input))
"Elapsed time: 198616.007581 msecs"
50000000` These happen to be the results I got.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik things are becoming interesting. i've run several times continuously, and the performance shows wave, but "reduce" way is faster in my tests: `red> (def input (range)) 
#'red/input
red> (time (reduce #(when (= %2 50000000) (reduced %2)) nil input)) 
"Elapsed time: 9708.709406 msecs"
red> (time (some #{50000000} input))
"Elapsed time: 27345.824046 msecs"
red> (def input (range)) 
#'red/input
red> (time (some #{50000000} input))
"Elapsed time: 42612.98816 msecs"
red> (time (reduce #(when (= %2 50000000) (reduced %2)) nil input)) 
"Elapsed time: 6802.505188 msecs"`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I used JDK 8 and clojure 1.7.

Comment: @xando The main point here should be that this is not a reliable way to measure, and it is especially not reliable at establishing the causes of those delays. For example, if I just slightly reduce the count from 50 million to 40 million, the times are both within 5 seconds. Further, the advantage of `reduce` is that it relies on the special-cased ability of a `range` to reduce itself; `some` is not coded in terms of `reduce` (but not essentially so---Clojure just isn't optimized aggressively enough). If you use `(remove odd? (range))`, the advantage of `reduce` is gone.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik just share some of my findings :-)

Comment: @xando Actually you started out by stating that `some` uses more resources and that `reduced` can shortcut the whole calculation while taking less resources. This is true only in the exceptional case of using a pure `range` or other sequence/collection which can directly reduce itself. Plus, all the alternatives obviously short circuit (`range` being an infinite sequence).

Comment: This solution looks like it would retain the head, and would take up a lot of memory? Is there a solution which takes constant space?

Answer (score 57):

In your case, the idiom is

```
(some #{1} [1 2 3 4])
```

How it works: #{1} is a set literal. A set is also a function evaluating to its arg if the arg is present in the set and to nil otherwise. Any set element is a "truthy" value (well, except for a boolean false, but that's a rarity in a set). `some` returns the return value of the predicate evaluated against the first collection member for which the result was truthy.

Comment: This is useful if you can search utilizing an element in entirety, but `some` will not return compound elements (such as hashmaps) if they are indexed partially.

Comment: `(->> [nil nil nil nil 42 nil nil] (some identity))` 42

Answer (score 26):

I tried several methods mentioned in this thread (JDK 8 and Clojure 1.7), and did some benchmark tests:

```
repl> (defn find-first
         [f coll]
         (first (filter f coll)))
#'cenx.parker.strategies.vzw.repl/find-first

repl> (time (find-first #(= % 50000000) (range)))
"Elapsed time: 5799.41122 msecs"
50000000

repl> (time (some #{50000000} (range)))
"Elapsed time: 4386.256124 msecs"
50000000

repl> (time (reduce #(when (= %2 50000000) (reduced %2)) nil (range)))
"Elapsed time: 993.267553 msecs"
50000000
```

The results show that `reduce` way may be the most efficient solution as in clojure 1.7.

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks for testing these, xando.  If would be better to have numbers from [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium), but my guess is that by searching for an item that's so far along in the sequence, the JVM has had a chance to optimize the code.

Answer (score 16):

[In 2016 there was a patch submitted to clojure core](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2056) that added an efficient shortcut for `(first (filter pred coll))` idiom, it was called `seek`.

The implementation avoided problems in herent with both the `(first (filter))` and `(some #(when (pred)))` alternatives. That is, it works efficiently with chunked sequences and plays nice with `nil?` and `false?` predicates.

Patch:

```
(defn seek
  "Returns first item from coll for which (pred item) returns true.
   Returns nil if no such item is present, or the not-found value if supplied."
  {:added  "1.9" ; note, this was never accepted into clojure core
   :static true}
  ([pred coll] (seek pred coll nil))
  ([pred coll not-found]
   (reduce (fn [_ x]
             (if (pred x)
               (reduced x)
               not-found))
           not-found coll)))
```

Examples:

```
(seek odd? (range)) => 1
(seek pos? [-1 1]) => 1
(seek pos? [-1 -2] ::not-found) => ::not-found
(seek nil? [1 2 nil 3] ::not-found) => nil
```

Eventually the patch was rejected:

> Upon review, we've decided that we do not wish to include this. Use of linear search (and in particular nested linear search) leads to poor performance - often it's better to use other kinds of data structures and that's why this functionality has not been included in the past.  ~Alex Miller 12/May/17 3:34 PM

Comment: According to the Jira ticket, the patch was declined. They do not want encourage people to use inefficient linear search. Makes sense to me :)
https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-2056

Answer (score 12):

I think `some` is the best tool for the job:

```
(some #(if (= % 1) %) '(3 4 1))
```

Comment: This does not suffer from the chunked sequences effect. But doesn't work in cases where `1` is `nil` or `false`. YMMV.

Comment: Wait... how can 1 equal nil? :) anyway, Matthew specified that elements should 'evaluate to true' so I think the behavior is the desired.

Comment: Consider `f` to be `#(contains? #{0 "false" false} %)`. And he said "evaluates a fn to true".

Answer (score 7):

Using `drop-while` instead of `filter` should address "over-application" of `f` for chunked sequences:

```
(defn find-first [f coll]
  (first (drop-while (complement f) coll)))
;;=> #'user/find-first

(find-first #(= % 1) [3 4 1])
;;=> 1
```

Comment: Cool solution :). I tested to ensure laziness. ```(find-first #(do (println %) (even? %)) [1 3 2 5 7 9])```, returns 2 and doesn't print 5, 7, or 9.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in clojure is sort like you might do it in Scheme.

```clj
(defn call-with-found
  "Call the given predicate, pred, on successive elements of the collection
  until the first time pred returns a truthy value, at which time if-found
  is called with that element of the collection, and call-with-found returns
  the return value of if-found.   If no such element of collection is found
  (including if collection is empty) then the value if-not-found (defaulting
  to false) is returned."
  ([pred coll & {:keys [if-found if-not-found]
                 :or {if-found (constantly true)
                      if-not-found false}}]
   (reduce (fn [_ item]
             (if (pred item)
               (reduced (if-found item))
               if-not-found)) if-not-found coll)))
```

The function `call-with-found` is called with a `predicate` and a `collection`. We search the collection until we find an element which satisfies the predicate, at which point we call the `if-found` continuation with that value, else we return the `if-not-found` value.